# My scrollTop() jQuery method hangs browser once scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am developing  a single page scroll site and its scrolls nicely. But whenever I hits the scroll to top div, it takes me to the up most position but after whenever I tried to go down the site it hangs up. Let me know what I am doing wrong in my jQuery.

Issue is more wild under Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/swapnesh/jSa3z/

**Script** -

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        //assigning the object
        var $bgobj = $(this);

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var yPos = $(window).scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed');

            var coords = '50%' + yPos + 'px';

            //Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition : coords });
        })
    })

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > 600 ) {
            $('#scrollpage').fadeIn();
            $('#scrollpage').click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
                return false;
            })
        }
        else {
            $('#scrollpage').fadeOut();
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="home" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
    <article>Swapnesh Sinha</article>
</section>

<section id="about" data-type="background" data-type="10" class="pages">
    <article>Web Developer - PHP, MYSQL, WORDPRESS</article>
</section>

<div id="scrollpage"></div>
```

Comment: You're assigning event handlers to the window inside a loop, which means the event handler is executed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollPage element is not dynamically created, so you only need to attach the clock event handler once (outside the window scroll event handler)

```
$('#scrollpage').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 600 ) {
        $('#scrollpage').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('#scrollpage').fadeOut();
    }
})
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jSa3z/3/

Comment: @cernumnos Thx for the answer +1 and green tick :)